# Update attributes of embedded new record in Rails & Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to write a piece of functionality that creates a record from a template in my Rails app, but with some customisations from the user.

The difficulty comes when trying to let the user override a field in an embedded document: the document is duplicated rather than updated.

I start with an object of type, let's say, `ExternalLinkGroupTemplate`, and it contains a number of `ExternalLink`s. It's used to create an `ExternalLinkGroup` which also contains `ExternalLink`s. The user should be able to edit the link text when it's cloned but not the URL, so the user is presented with a form When it's copied the user should be able to I can create a copy of it with (simplified because some of the code is in different files, remove tests for success etc):

```
@link_group = ExternalLinkGroup.new
@template.links.each do {|link| @new_link_group.links.push link.dup }
@link_group.update_attributes(params[:link_group])
```

When the link group is created, it contains twice as many links as the template, and only the second set has the changes. Clearly, Mongoid/ActiveWhatever is creating new items rather than updating existing ones.

I don't want to just pass through all the fields in the parameters without duplicating anything because there's actually some inheritance going on and some of the links will be of different types and have extra fields, and I don't want to code a partial for each of them that just has a bunch of hidden fields. Also, I don't want the user to be able to modify the hidden fields and submit whatever.

I can't reference them by `_id` because they're not saved yet. I was expecting the array index of `template[links_attributes]` to be sufficient but it's not.

What do?

Using Rails 3.2.13, MongoDB 2.2.x, Mongoid 3.0.5.